# How to remove a simple embedded document from mongodb document

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following document with the nested subdocument called subdoc:

```
{
    _id : 1,
    afield : 'value'
    subdoc: {
        _id : 1,
        field: 'abc'
    }
}
```

How can I remove the subdoc?

Regards,
Gerard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$unset` operator to remove the field.

```
db.collection.update({queryhere},{$unset: {subdoc:1},{multi:true}})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For some reason I missed the unset operator, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You  can use [$unset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

```
db.collectionName.update(
    { 'subdoc': { '$exists': true } },   // check if exist 
    { '$unset': { 'subdoc': true  } },  // unset it 
    { 'multi': true }                    // Options for multiple doc 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for offering this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be

```
db.collectionName.find().ForEach(function(d){

delete d.fieldName;
db.collectionName.save(d);

})
```

Comment: Don't quite understand this solution! But that's probably to do with the fact that I'm a novice MongoDB user! So that requires a better understanding!

Comment: mongodb is javascript based, you can use javascript functions to manipulate data.In the above solution you are iterating through all the documents in the collection. At any instant the document is represented by 'd' and using 'delete',you delete the fieldname from that document and then save the document with field deleted.